# Почему при передвижение по 2 мерному массиву указатель прыгает на 16 байт

Tags: c++, c, указатели

У меня есть двумерный массив `**parr` он заполнен случайными числами 
Есть вот такой участок

```
int **ptr = 0;
ptr = parr;
cout << *ptr << ' ';
ptr = ptr+1;
cout << *ptr << ' ';
cout << endl;
```

В котором я смотрю как изменяется адрес, вместо передвижению на 4 байта у меня указатель передвигается на 16 байт. Хочу понять почему так происходит и как двигать указатель на 4 байта?

[image: Скриншот из консоли]

Comment: А почему вы считаете, что указатель передвигается на 16 байт? Вы ведь не выводите значение указателя.

Comment: На скриншоте последняя строка - это вывод того кусочка кода, что я написал вверху

Comment: Но в вашем коде вы не выводите значение указателя, который вы увеличиваете. Вы увеличиваете `ptr`, а выводите `*ptr`. Это разные вещи.

Comment: А разве `*ptr` 'это не будет разыменование указателя `ptr` чтобы получить по нему значение?

Comment: Всё, я вроде как разобрался, спасибо за помощь